# Is there a comprehensive list of what all the Halacha L'Moshe M'Sinai are?

Tags: halacha, halacha-lemoshe-misinai

- Tefillin have to be black
- *Lavud* (two things are within less than three tefachim of each other, they are considered to be touching, and therefore contiguous)
- all the types of *shiurim* (measurements)
- *orlah* outside of Eretz Yisrael

... are just some of the many *Halacha L'Moshe M'Sinai*

Does a comprehensive list of what all the *Halacha L'Moshe M'Sinai* are exist?

Comment: Have you seen [this](http://hebrewbooks.org/19278)? Such a list would be subject to ramification due to differences of opinion as well. ([cf.](https://www.yeshiva.org.il/wiki/index.php?title=%D7%9E%D7%99%D7%A7%D7%A8%D7%95%D7%A4%D7%93%D7%99%D7%94_%D7%AA%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%95%D7%93%D7%99%D7%AA:%D7%94%D7%9C%D7%9B%D7%94_%D7%9C%D7%9E%D7%A9%D7%94_%D7%9E%D7%A1%D7%99%D7%A0%D7%99))

Comment: @NoachMiFrankfurt def a duplicate- searched the HLMM tag and that answer didn't show up (just added it now) thanks!